# MySQL get the sum of all rows without retrieving all of them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This may be a little confusing but please bear with me. Here's the thing:

I have a database that contains ~1000 records, as the following table illustrates:

```
+------+----------+----------+
| id   | date     | amount   |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0001 | 14/01/15 |      100 |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0002 | 14/02/04 |      358 |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0003 | 14/05/08 |     1125 |
+------+----------+----------+
```

What I want to do is this:

1. Retrieve all the records beginning at 2014 and until yesterday:

   ```
   WHERE `date` > '14-01-01' AND `date` < CURDATE()
   ```
2. But also get the sum of `amount` up to the current date, this is:

   ```
   WHERE `date` < CURDATE()
   ```

I've already got this working by just selecting all the records based on the second condition, getting the sum, and then excluding those which don't match the first condition. Something like this:

```
SELECT `id`, `date`, `amount` FROM `table`
WHERE `date` < CURDATE()
```

And then:

```
$rows = fetchAll($PDOStatement);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $sum += $row->amount;
    if (
        strtotime($row->date) > strtotime('14-01-01') &&
        strtotime($row->date) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))
    ) {
        $valid_rows[] = $row;
    }
}
unset $rows;
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a single query, efficiently? Would a *transaction* be more efficient than sorting out the records in PHP? This has to be SQL-standard compliant (I'll be doing this on MySQL and SQLite).

Update:

It doesn't matter if the result ends up being something like this:

```
+------+----------+----------+-----+
| id   | date     | amount   | sum |
+------+----------+----------+-----+
| 0001 | 14/01/15 |      100 | 458 |
+------+----------+----------+-----+
| 0002 | 14/02/04 |      358 | 458 |
+------+----------+----------+-----+
| 0003 | 14/05/08 |     1125 | 458 |
+------+----------+----------+-----+
```

The worst case would be when the resulting set ends up being the same as the set that gives the sum (in this case appending the sum would be irrelevant and would cause an overhead), but for any other *regular* cases the bandwith save would be huge.

Comment: With 2 different conditions you will probably always need 2 different queries. But 2 queries might be more efficient that the loop you have now, especially if the total number of records is large compared to the sub-total.

Comment: you need 2 queries to get the answer: 1 - to get the records, 1 to get the sum

Comment: Ok, I get the 2 queries part, can I use a transaction and a variable to achieve this? would this be more efficient than sorting the records out in php?

Comment: What shall your result look like? Your first query shall retrieve records (with several columns probably), the second shall return one number. So how do you want to see this in one result set? Please show an example.

Comment: I think the only plausible solution would be to append the sum to every row of the result set

Comment: This would give you the same value in every row. Why would you do this? What do you want to achieve actually? Why do you want to get two different things with one query instead of simply writing two queries?

Comment: Imagine an accounting application where you need to know how much money do you have saved up until today but you only want to know details of the records of the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a special record with your sum and add it at the end of your first query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` > '14-01-01' AND `date` < CURDATE()
UNION
SELECT 9999, CURDATE(), SUM(`amount`) FROM `table` WHERE `date` < CURDATE()
```

Then you will have all your desired record and the record with id 9999 or whatever is your sum

Comment: He said he has 1000 records ... The 9999 is just an idea it could be -1 or 10000

Comment: This is great, can you show me an example of a result set using this approach? I'm not on my coding PC and away of any DB.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

You can get the SUM using a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
    SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`date`, t2.sum_amount
    FROM
    `table` t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT SUM(`amount`) sum_amount
        FROM `table`
        WHERE `date` < CURDATE()
    ) t2
   ON 1 = 1
   WHERE t1.`date` > STR_TO_DATE('01,1,2014','%d,%m,%Y') AND t1.`date` < CURDATE();
```

Comment: That does not get any records nor does it get the total sum up to the current date; it just gets a partial sum which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @jeroen Thank you for your feedback! I did not understand completely at first. The above query should satisfy both the conditions and get the sum as well.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by correlated subquery, something like below:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM t WHERE t.date < t1.date) AS PrevAmount
FROM        t AS t1
WHERE `date` > '14-01-01' AND `date` < CURDATE()
```

However it is very unefficient  if the number of records is large.

Answer (score 1):

It's hackish, but:

```
> select * from foo;
+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |
|    4 |    4 |
|    5 |    5 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

> select * from foo
left join (
    select sum(val)
    from foo
    where id < 3
) AS bar ON 1=1
where id < 4;
+------+------+----------+
| id   | val  | sum(val) |
+------+------+----------+
|    1 |    1 |        3 |
|    2 |    2 |        3 |
|    3 |    3 |        3 |
+------+------+----------+
```

Basically, do your summing in a joined subquery. That'll attach the sum result to every row in the outer table's results. You'll waste a bit of bandwidth sending that duplicated value out with every row, but it does get you the results in a "single" query.

Comment: I think the wasted bandwith would be far less that that of sending all the records back.

Comment: That'd depend on if you're only getting a few hundred/thousand records from the outer query, or a few trillion. Wasting a gig of bandwidth just to keep from having to run two queries gets into the ludicrous range. at some point the wastage will be higher than the overhead of two separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want it to do...optimizing the subquery is the real challenge:

```
SELECT id,date,amount,(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table) AS total_amount
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '14-01-01' AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```